# NTFS mounts as read-only under Linux

Tags: windows, ntfs, read-only

Recently had this problem while running an android project out of my Windows drive.  After rebooting Linux, things went awry.

My windows partition mounts in the `/media/user` folder, but it's always read only.

All the usual tricks have failed: running `chkdsk`, rebooting, holding <kbd>shift</kbd> + shutdown.

Comment: try `sudo ntfs-3g /dev/sdaX /media/$USER/windows` or `sudo mount -o remount,rw /dev/sdaX /media/$USER/windows`. also post the output of **/etc/fstab**

Answer (score 2):

yes, the output of mount was helpful.  i ran `sudo mount -t ntfs /dev/sdb2 /mnt/windows`, and it said “Windows is hibernated, refused to mount”

i went into windows and ran these commands as a command prompt admin `powercfg -h off` and `shutdown /s /t 0`

The fall creators update is weird in how it manages reboots, opening everything up where you left off.  Even if you disable quick boot, hibernation.  I read using the classic reboot menu (press `alt+F4` on desktop) also works (if you hold shift or use reboot)